# Cloning Mutated Creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Mutate is a new mechanic in Ikoria. A lot has been said about how it works, but cloning is something I can't find mentioned on the net. Not sure if the comp rules have been updated yet, but my impression is that as it is one creature, a clone would get all of the mutated abilities. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Cloning a mutated creature copies all the existing mutations

This interaction has been put together by a modification of the first layer of continuous effect interactions and two new rules.

> 613.1a Layer 1: Rules and effects that modify copiable values are applied.

Previously, this layer applied 'copy effects'.  Now it's been generalized to apply 'copiable values', of which includes the newly created category of "merged permanents"

> 721.2a A merged permanent has only the characteristics of its topmost component, unless otherwise specified by the effect that caused them to merge. This is a copiable effect whose timestamp is the time the objects merged. (See rule 613.2.)

And mutate, the effect causing the permanents to merge, modifies the characteristics to include the rules text of the other objects.

> 702.139e A mutated permanent has all abilities of each card and token that represents it. Its other characteristics are derived from the topmost card or token.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how mutate is handled by the new rules.

However, the easiest way to handle it, from a rules standpoint, would be to generate a text changing (or ability granting) continuous effect. In this case, only the top creature would be copied.

I cannot think of a way to make the mutated abilities copiables safe from defining the mutated creature as a new card. It is possible they might go this way instead (similar to meld cards).

Comment: Thanks. This is more of a comment than an answer, so I'll leave it unanswered for now, but maybe once the rules are established it will become clear.

Comment: In fact, from the article, I think it's more likely the copy will have all abilities: "As a mutating creature spell resolves, instead of entering the battlefield, it merges with its target into one creature... You'll end up with a pile of cards... that all represents a single creature."

Comment: If this “pile of cards” is treated as a single card then yes.
If that is the case, then the whole pile will be bounced together (and they would probably be un-mutated when flickered). This is an indication that would gives out the rules.

Comment: You raise a good point re. flicker... I know that if the target is bounced/removed while it's on the stack, it will etb as the creature version (similar to Bestow), but I wonder what bounce/flicker does?

Comment: @Soulus101 MaRo has said on Tumblr that flicker effects will return a whole bunch of creatures. Don't have time to find the source right now, though.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus That was my guess for how it would work because they would have no memory of being cast using Mutate.